# There is no EconoMode in printer options

Tags: printing, hp

I check the [EconoMode](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c00763650) and it works in Windows but there is no option in `http://localhost:631` or printer properties. However there are another options like `printing quality (Normal/Draft)` or `print density (Light/Dark)` that seems do similar work (But not exacltly). So is there any way to add EconoMode option?

I also try hplip and adding `EconoMode` to `Other Options (Advanced)`.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and laserjet p1102 printer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looking at this through HPLIP Have you tried looking at this via [CUPS](http://localhost:631); it is the standards-based, open source printing system developed by Apple Inc. for OS® X and other UNIX®-like operating systems.You should be able to select "fast draft"?

Good luck.